# Printing garbage value while converting farenheit to centigrade using C program

Tags: c

Can anyone help me in writing a c program to convert Celsius to Fahrenheit with only 2 precisions without using any format specifiers.
When I tried using the following code, garbage values are being displayed in the output :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{
    float celsius,farenheit;
    clrscr();
    printf("\nEnter the temparature in celsius");
    scanf("%f",&celsius);
    farenheit=(1.8*celsius)+32.0;
    farenheit=farenheit*100;
    farenheit=farenheit/100;
    printf("The farenheit temcalcparature is:%f",farenheit);
    getch();
}
```

Can anyone help me in completing the code?

Comment: Can you please show us your input and corresponding output? Why the output is "garbage"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [rounding functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding-Functions.html), but it is better to use format specifiers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
void main()
{
    float celsius,farenheit;
    celsius = 123.12567;
    printf("The temparature in celsius:%f\n", celsius);
    farenheit=(1.8*celsius)+32.0;
    printf("The farenheit temparature is:%f\n",farenheit);
    printf("The farenheit temparature is:%0.2f\n",farenheit);
    printf("The farenheit temparature is:%d.%d", (int)farenheit, (int)(rint(farenheit*100))%100);
}
```

Output

```
The temparature in celsius:123.125671
The farenheit temparature is:253.626205
The farenheit temparature is:253.63
The farenheit temparature is:253.63
```

Comment: Hi Peter, When I am trying to compile the very same program you mentioned above I am getting error with regards to the last line. Could you please look into the error in the last line

Comment: Which error? Do you link with math library (`-lm`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
farenheit=(1.8*celsius)+32.0;
printf("The farenheit temcalcparature is:%0.2f",farenheit);
```

will give you what you want